# Pyspark streaming data aggregate does not output data in append mode, but does in complete and update

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I'm trying to do an aggregate operation on streamed data, and save it as a csv file. If I do that, I get empty files, but if I output it to the console in either update or complete output mode, the data does show up properly.

Here is what my code looks like currently:

```
df3 = df3.withColumn("timestamp", current_timestamp())

df4 = df3 \
    .withWatermark("timestamp", "3 seconds") \
    .groupBy(window("timestamp", "3 seconds", "1 seconds"), "Ort") \
    .count()

out = df4 \
    .writeStream \
    .format("console") \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .start()

out.awaitTermination()
```

Edit:
I found out it's working fine, the issue has to do with not getting new data from kafka (at the moment, there is no new data), which causes the window to never finish (all columns have the same timestamp). So the question is - is there a way to force the window to finish after some time has passed?

Comment: Please add the write method and parameters passed

Comment: I added them to the post